# do I need to run "update-initramfs" and "update-grub" after "sudo make && sudo make modules_install && sudo make install"?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am hacking linux-4.13.4. I find some posts, like [this one](http://www.ramkitech.com/2012/04/how-to-compile-kernel-step-by-step.html) about how to compile and make kernel.

I am not sure do we need to do

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.13.4 
sudo update-grub
```

after

```
sudo make -j 32 && sudo make modules_install -j 32 && sudo make install -j 32
```

Since I find that when I finish running `sudo make -j 32 && sudo make modules_install -j 32 && sudo make install -j 32`, at the end of the log

```
  ...
  ...
  INSTALL sound/usb/snd-usbmidi-lib.ko
  INSTALL sound/usb/usx2y/snd-usb-usx2y.ko
  INSTALL virt/lib/irqbypass.ko
  INSTALL sound/usb/usx2y/snd-usb-us122l.ko
  DEPMOD  4.13.4
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 4.13.4 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
    System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.13.4 /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.4
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.4 /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.4


update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.4    <----


run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.13.4 /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.4
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.13.4 /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.4
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.13.4 /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.4
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd 4.13.4 /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.4
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.13.4 /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.4


Generating grub configuration file ...    
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.4    <----
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.4
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.4.old
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.4
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

If I run `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.13.4` and `sudo update-grub` again, the log seems the same as the last part of the above one

```
wxf@wxfvbox:~/kernelSources/linux-4.13.4$ sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.13.4
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.4


wxf@wxfvbox:~/kernelSources/linux-4.13.4$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.4
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.4
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.4.old
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.4
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

#### So, my question is do I need to run `update-initramfs` and `update-grub` after `sudo make && sudo make modules_install && sudo make install` ?

Comment: There can be variations in the tools various distributions provide, but a good reference is [Kernels/Traditional compilation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels/Traditional_compilation). Your question is more properly asked on the StackExchange site [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is more properly asked on the StackExchange site [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.